# Initialize object properties as class properties first in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, coding-style

I have the habit to initialize the properties of an instance of a class in the constructor of that class but, in case the properties are very tight to the class, I also declare them and initialize them to `None` (`[]` or some other base value) as properties in the class.

For instance:

```
 class AClass(object):
      aprop = None

      def __init__(self):
           self.aprop = "avalue"
```

Which in most of the cases it won't make much of a difference from just doing:

```
 class AClass(object):

      def __init__(self):
           self.aprop = "avalue"
```

However, if somebody gets the scope of the `AClass` will notice that an instance of this class is expected to have an attribute named `aprop`. I think of it as a placeholder for the property `aprop` in the class.

This looks to me more as a question of style, but I would like to know whether this is a good practice. Would you recommend it? Is it something common?  or should I try to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `self.aprop = "avalue"` in the `__init__` function, every instance of `AClass` will have the `aprop` property since `__init__` is called when you initiate an instance. This makes `aprop` an *instance variable*.

When you do `aprop = None` you add a *class variable* to `AClass`. This means that the class itself will have this property.

For Example:

```
>>> class AClass(object):
...       def __init__(self):
...            self.aprop = "avalue"
...
>>> AClass.aprop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'AClass' has no attribute 'aprop'
```

And:

```
>>> class AClass(object):
...       aprop = None
...       def __init__(self):
...            self.aprop = "avalue"
...
>>> AClass.aprop
>>> print AClass.aprop
None
```

So if you want your class to have this property you should define it as a class variable. If you only use it in instances, the only case you should define a class property is if you don't always redefine it (hide it) in `__init__`:

```
class AClass(object):
      aprop = None
      def __init__(self):
           self.bprop = "bvalue"
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you ever access the property on the class itself (e.g. as `AClass.aprop`) rather than on an instance, there's no need to make it a class member if you always populate it on an instance in the `__init__` method.

My vote is to always write the least amount of code necessary to clearly convey the intent. Adding an extra member to the class obscures the intent (since your actual goal here is for it to be an instance property) and is unnecessary: that sounds like two strikes against it.